# Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql

I was given a problem by my professor and have to create the database to his specifications. Here is my code:

```
create table item
(ItemName varchar (30) not null,
BaseCost float,
constraint pk_item primary key(ItemName)
);

create table laundry
(ItemName varchar (30) not null,
WashCost float,
constraint pk_laundry primary key (ItemName),
constraint fk_item foreign key (ItemName) references 
item(ItemName)
);

create table dryClean
(ItemName varchar (30) not null,
DryCost float,
constraint pk_dryClean primary key (ItemName),
constraint fk_item foreign key (ItemName) references 
item(ItemName)
);
```

the `ItemName` for `laundry` and `dryСlean` are the primary keys for their tables but also the foreign key back to the `Item` table. I dont know how to create these realtionships without making duplicate keys. Do you have suggestions? I dont want the answer because this is an assignment but some suggestions how to solve the problem. thanks

Comment: given you're making the laundry.itemname and dryclean.itemname fields into PKs in their table, you'd be enforcing a 1:1 relationship, which means those fields could just as well be in the main item table.

Comment: Yes they are 1:1 and I agree they could be in the Item table but the professor wants them all in 3 separate tables. Is there a way for me to do the three tables to conform to his expectations?

Answer (score 0):

In such situation, you can use a composite primary key, one for order id -like the identifier in the bill- and other for order item -pants for example-

```
create table laundry
(orderid int AUTO_INCREMENT,
ItemName varchar (30) not null,
WashCost float,
constraint pk_laundry primary key (orderid,ItemName),
constraint fk_item foreign key (ItemName) references 
item(ItemName)
);

create table dryClean
(orderid int AUTO_INCREMENT,
ItemName varchar (30) not null,
DryCost float,
constraint pk_dryClean primary key (orderid,ItemName),
constraint fk_item foreign key (ItemName) references 
item(ItemName)
);
```

and there are many other options if you are free to choose table structure ... like master(order)/detail(order items)